# Keeping fixed sidebar 79% from left but still have no white space

Tags: css

I want to keep a rotated fixed sidebar exactly 79% from the left but when I add `white-space: nowrap;` it messes up the location. Perhaps its easier to get the sidebar to stay exactly a # of px's away from a middle div?

https://jsfiddle.net/cs6bya2g/embedded/result/

```
#sidebar-miniright {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left:79%;
width:25%;
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-270deg);
/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-270deg);
transform: rotate(-270deg);
}

.sidebar-right {
width:auto;
}
```

[image]

[image]

^ This is what I want always. But when I resize browser it becomes like the following pic. When I add `white-space: nowrap;` it causes the `left: 79%;` to become wonky.

Comment: `white-space` doesn't accept `none` as a value - what exactly are you trying to achieve? (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: @Luca Sorry, I meant nowrap. :p

Comment: Adding it seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/cs6bya2g/2/. Is it a specific browser issue perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Your sidebar element is rotated on its side**,** which means `width: 25%` will make the sidebar**'**s height be 25% the width of the window**.**

A solution is to delete the `width: 25%` rule**.** Update your `transform` properties to**:**

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg) translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: rotate(-270deg) translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform: rotate(-270deg) translateX(-50%);
-o-transform: rotate(-270deg) translateX(-50%);
transform: rotate(-270deg) translateX(-50%);
```

This will center the sidebar text vertically**.** You can play around with the `translateX` values to get the desired result**.**